# Why there is no `self` in the closure in the function `makeConstraints` by SnapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, snapkit

```
starLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.equalTo(starImageView.snp.right).offset(5)
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

The `starImageView` and `starLabel` are the properties of current view controller. But, why can I ignore the `self`(`self.starImageView`) in the closure which is the param in `makeConstraints`?

And in my closure, I must write the `self` explicitly, or the compiler will report a error:

> Reference to property 'starImageView' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
>
> Insert 'self.'

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public func makeConstraints(_ closure: (_ make: ConstraintMaker) -> Void) {
        ConstraintMaker.makeConstraints(item: self.view, closure: closure)
}
```

Because the closure is not `@escaping`，so it means the closure will just run in the function. When the function over the closure will be released.
Only the function can hold the closure.

Answer (score -1):

It's because `equalTo` looks like this:

```
public func equalTo(_ other: ConstraintRelatableTarget, _ file: String = #file, _ line: UInt = #line) -> ConstraintMakerEditable {
    return self.relatedTo(other, relation: .equal, file: file, line: line)
}
```

And `ConstraintRelatableTarget` is a protocol that leads to different types as Int, Float etc. You also have a reference to a `ConstraintItem` which is this case is the view you refer to, and this is how it looks:

```
internal weak var target: AnyObject?
internal let attributes: ConstraintAttributes

internal init(target: AnyObject?, attributes: ConstraintAttributes) {
    self.target = target
    self.attributes = attributes
}

internal var layoutConstraintItem: LayoutConstraintItem? {
    return self.target as? LayoutConstraintItem
}
```

As it appears, both `Any?` and `AnyObject?` (I dont think it has to be optional) does not need self to be reached. Hence, anything you put in to the `equalTo` function, is seen by `snapKit` as an `AnyObject?` and therefor don't need a `self` reference.